# UITabBarController viewControllers strange behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

guys, I need your help with ObjectiveC and UITabBarController.

I have 2 pieces of code with the same (I hope) functionality. But works only second one. The task is  to dynamically create array of viewControllers and assign it to UITabBarController viewControllers property.

I have DZCustomTabBarController that inherits from UITabBarController.

```
@interface DZCustomTabBarController : UITabBarController

@end
```

and property `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *controllers;` that points to my dynamically created viewControllers like that.

Everything is happening in viewDidLoad method

Code below doesn't work

```
NSArray *titles = @[@"first", @"second"];

for (NSString *title in titles) {
    DZViewController *controller = [[DZViewController alloc] init];

    controller.title = title;

    [self.controllers addObject:controller];
}

self.viewControllers = self.controllers ;
```

and I can't figure out why.

But this piece of code works.

```
DZViewController *firstViewController = [[DZViewController alloc] init];
firstViewController.title = @"first";

DZViewController *secondViewController = [[DZViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.title = @"second";

self.viewControllers = @[firstViewController, secondViewController];
```

I'm not advanced at Objective C so I need your help. I think that problem in this line of code `[self.controllers addObject:controller];`

Comment: I think, your `controllers` property is used uninitialized. Try doing `self.controllers = [NSMutableArray array];` before using your `for-in` cycle. Good Luck!

Comment: Fahri Azimov, thanks, man, you realy save my day. You should post answer and I will mark it as resolve. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your `controllers` property is used uninitialized. Try doing `self.controllers = [NSMutableArray array];` before using your for-in cycle. Good Luck!